# When will this happen in PHP?

Tags: php, scope

This is a **contrived example**：

```
function test()
{
    global $a;
    $a=2;
}

test();

//here $a will report undefined variable

echo $a;
```

I meet this problem now by somehow,but I can't reproduce it in an easy way!

**EDIT**

I mean operations like `include` or alike by **when**

Comment: Code works just fine for me...

Comment: Yes,so the questions is `when` will it not work,I can't reproduce it in an easy way!

Comment: As no one else has pointed out, this is a misuse of `global`. The purpose of `global` is to make an already-defined global variable available inside a function's namespace, not to create a new variable in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You recently edited to say that is happens when you 'include' a file.

Files and Globaling don't really get along. You actually have to Global out and into a file. So if test1.php had this code

```
$a = 5;
```

and test2.php had this code:

```
$a = 3;
```

and test3.php had this code:

```
$a = 10;
```

and finally (Yes, too many files) testMaster.php had this code

```
include 'test1.php';
include 'test2.php';
include 'test3.php';
echo $a;
```

There would be an undefined variable error. You would have to go an individually global the variable in each file in order for them all to get set.

Now, I'm pretty sure this wouldn't affect the code you gave us, or if `function test()` was included, and then called `test();` and right after it you put `echo $a;`. But if you define AND call `test()` in a separate file than you `echo $a`, it would cause a globaling error.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but yes, this is a flaw in the include system.

Answer (score 0):

One way for you getting the *undefined variable* at the place you've mentioned is when you make `$a` local to function `test()` by not having the `global $a;` declaration.

```
<?php
function test()
{
    //global $a;
    $a=2;
}

test();

//here $a will report undefined variable

echo $a;
?>
```

The other could be you are calling the function `test()` **after** the `echo`:

```
<?php
function test()
{
    global $a;
    $a=2;
}


//here $a will report undefined variable

echo $a;

test();
?>
```

The variable a has not been initialized when its being printed and will result in `Notice: Undefined variable: a`

The snippet you've provided should work just fine. At the point where you are echoing `$a`, its    no more undefined and has been given a value in the function `test()`.

Comment: It's not the problem I met.There is `global` declaration and echo is after function call.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen if you do this inside test():

```
unset($GLOBALS['a']);
```

I doubt you are though, maybe you can update your post to provide a code sample that better resembles your situation.